# Why does setInputType disable autocorrection?

Tags: android

Normally the android keyboard automatically shows suggestions as you type (autocorrect), but if you change the properties of the edit field from your code, the suggestions no longer show up.

For instance, this line successfully changes the input type to use all caps, but suggestions no longer show up:

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
```

Even if I explicitly tell it to use autocorrect, it STILL doesn't use autocorrect:

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

However, if I never call setInputType, the suggestions show up just fine! Why does this happen? How do I fix it it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't remember the full story, but I had to do the following to make it work for me

```
edit.setRawInputType(edit.getInputType() & ~EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE);
```

note the calling of `setRawInputType` instead of `setInputType`

Comment: I'll mark this as the accepted answer, since it led me to the right answer. Turns out my code above was overwriting the TYPE_CLASS_TEXT flag. Your code preserves that flag using getInputType(). In my code, I was able to combine getInputType with the flags I want set, and it works now. Thanks!!